# Partial fft of multidimensional array

Tags: matlab, fftw

I have a 3D array of dimension `(NX,NY,NZ)` which represents a variable in physical space, let's say `velocities`, taken from a simulation in a 3D domain.

1) I want to Fourier-transform only the dimensions X and Z, how should I use the built-in function `fft` in this case? At some point I want to also get back to the physical space, but only on X, so the same question applies.

2) I read that FFTW uses only 2*N/3 points, should I specify NX and NZ as the number of retained modes or fewer?

3) When using the FFTW package, is there any issue with the coefficient in front of the integral defining the Fourier transformation? Does this package assume that my domain is 2pix2pix2pi?

Comment: Why can't you (1) just FFT it all and get rid if the unwanted data, or (2) make a sub-array (NX,NZ) and FFT that?  Is the issue the FFT function or the array manipulation?

Comment: I need the data in Y in physical space, so I guess my first question is about manipulation/use of fft routine only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1°) The function for 2D FFT is `fft2`, and it will by default apply to the two first dimensions of the array. That is, `fft2(velocities)` will give you a 3D array with `NZ` Fourier transforms along dimensions *X* and *Y*

In order to do the FFT along other dimensions, you have to manually decompose the 2D FFT as two 1D FFTs. `fft` will work by default along dimension 1 and produce as many samples as there were in the input. `fft(X[],n)` does the same, but along dimension *n*.

Thus, you may compute a 2D FFT of your 3D array, along dimensions X and Z with the command:

```
my_FFT = fft(fft(velocities),[],3);
```

2°) There will be as many samples out as samples in.

3°) I believe the normalization by the size of the array is fully applied on the reverse transform, and not at all on the direct transform.

```
fft([1 0 0 0 0 0])
ans =
     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

To maintain normalization, a coefficient `sqrt(NX*NZ)` should be applied (multiply when doing FFT, divide when doing an IFFT).

Comment: Thank you! Regarding (3), apart from multiplying/dividing by sqrt(NX*NZ), shouldn't I do the opposite with sqrt(2pi*2pi) (dividing/multiplying) ?. Isn't this the default coefficient that fft uses? I am bit lost in this point.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment is wrong. However, after reading a bit I think it's the opposite of what you said @Brice. Can you confirm this? Thank you.